# How to get function of median from numpy?

Tags: python

What is the numpy function where  it lets you use the median function(code to do that if you know) `from bumpy import median alternative pls`

Comment: Just https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: median of an array:

```
 import numpy as np

 a = np.array([[10, 7, 4], [3, 2, 1]])
 print np.median(a)
```